# Supervisor : Why am I able to run more than 4 processes on a 4 core machine?

Tags: vagrant, multiprocessing, tornado, supervisord

I'm working on a 4 core machine and using a vagrant box to host my application. I've configured Supervisor to spawn 5 processes on different ports and I can easily run all the processes independently. Does this mean that each processes spawned by Supervisor does not adhere to an individual core ?

Comment: If you want to limit processes to cpu cores you'd have to set the process' cpu affinity: http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset rarely useful though.

Comment: Just to be clear, you have 4 core on the host or the vm ? even if you have 4 core on the host, the vm will not have the 4 cores as well unless you declare it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running processes is the OS job. It decides what to run and when to run it. 
The fact that you have 4 cores means that you can execute 4 different "codes"   in parallel (4 different threads not necessarily from the same process)

That means that if you put 4 processes on the same machine with 4 cores, chances are they will all run in parallel. 
If you have 5 processes than at any given moment, only 4 are running, but it will seem like they are all running in parallel, because they will do a "context switch",  your cores will randomly stop running 1 process and switch to the other

Comment: Does this mean that if submit a job simultaneously (theoretically) on all the 5 processes, one of them would fail ?

Comment: no it will not fail, it will simply "wait". actually you will not even notice, one of your cores will simply work on one process for a few miliseconds, then switch to the another process for a few miliseconds, and back to the first one and so on. it simply means that they will not run really in parralel but they will just "seem" to do so

Comment: It just means at a meantime only 4 processes can run. OS will handle which processes to run out of 5 at the meantime . Simple way would be to use round robin which gives equal chance for every process to run in a cycle.